# Generate JSON with multiple nodes with the same name

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I need to create objects in c# that get converted to the following JSON:

```
{
    "Order": {
        "CustomerCode": "9999999",
        "Note": "New Order for Test -- UNIT TEST",
        "Stops": {
            "Stop": {
                "Sequence": "1",
                "StopType": "P",
                "Name": "CVS"
            },
            "Stop": {
                "OrderStopID": "5",
                "Sequence": "2",
                "StopType": "D",
            }           
        },
        "Jobs": {
            "Job": {
                "Sequence": "1",
                "Drivers": {
                    "Driver": {
                        "Sequence": "1",
                        "DriverCode": "09"
                    },
                    "Driver": {
                        "Sequence": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the objects I created to represt this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}


public class Order
{
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public List<Stop> Stops { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

When I use JSON.NET to serialize the root object I get the following:

Notice taht hte Stops and Jobs are generated as an array, how do I make it so it gets genrated as the JSON is showed at the beginning?

```
   {
      "Order": {
        "CustomerCode": "9999999",
        "Stops": [
          {
            "Sequence": "1",
            "StopType": "P",
            "Name": "CVS"
          },
          {
            "OrderStopID": "5",
            "Sequence": "2",
            "StopType": "D",
          }
        ],
        "Jobs": [
          {
            "Sequence": "1",
            "Drivers": [
              {
                "Sequence": "1",
                "DriverCode": "09"
              },
              {
                "Sequence": "2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: The JSON that you're trying to generate does not validate under any of the standards on this [validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Why are you trying to generate JSON like this?

Comment: @John There's a POST API that only accepts this format as the request data

Comment: You will probably need a custom converter to get the desired format

Comment: You also have a wayward comma after `"StopType": "D",`

Comment: OP, based on your now-deleted other question, I've added the "read" part of the `JsonConverter` to my original answer to this question. I hope this helps. :-)

Comment: @John - The JSON in the post is mostly valid (obviously unusual) - http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf -  "The JSON syntax does not impose any restrictions on
the strings used as names, does not require that name strings be unique, and does not assign any
significance to the ordering of name/value pairs". Comma in `"StopType": "D",` is wrong (but that's only problem).

Comment: @Alexei Hmm, I wonder why the validator I used doesn't validate it under that standard. Weird. Anyway, hopefully my solution is good enough for OP.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not even sure it parses in ECMA script.

Comment: @John I assumed most people complain about duplicate "property" names (which are ok but trouble for many parsers), trailing comma is not ok (but accepted by most parsers) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `JsonConverter` for this:

```
public class ArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly string _propertyName;

    public ArrayConverter(string propertyName)
    {
        this._propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType && objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        IList items = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        var modelType = objectType.IsArray ? objectType.GetElementType() : objectType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(reader), "Expected object.");
        }

        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            reader.Read();
            items.Add(serializer.Deserialize(reader, modelType));
        }

        return items;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable enumerableValue)
        {
            JObject obj = new JObject();
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (var val in enumerableValue)
            {
                writer.WritePropertyName(_propertyName);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, val);
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), "Value does not implement IEnumerable.");
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/VNUL29774)

Comment: it seems as if the 3rd level objects it's only getting hte last one, example I'm getting the two "Stop" objects into an array but I'm only getting the last Driver object which has one level of indentation deeper, can't seem to figure out why at the 3rd level it only takes the last object instead of adding the two drivers to the array

Comment: any idea with the 3rd indentation "Drivers" is only writing the last one?

Comment: @Eric I've no idea. I got as far as finding that it never seems to offer more than one to the "read" part of the converter. I'm too sleepy to look into it anymore now though :-( I'll try to find time tomorrow. I might have to download JSON.NET's code and debug through to get an idea.

Comment: no worries man get some sleep, health is more important, I'll try to debug it and see what I can come up with but I think the code might need more modification to allow for 3rd level indentation Order -> Jobs -> Job,Job,Job -> Drivers (Driver, Driver) the second Driver is overriding the first one, it's the WriteJson function

Comment: unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out what's wrong, if you have time and only if you have time are you able to look into it? Thank you

Comment: @Eric Well... uh, it looks like duplicates are removed by JSON.NET. See [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JTokenWriter.cs#L178-L180)

Comment: @Eric I've modified it to work. I limited it to only work with `List<T>` and not others, so you might need to tweak it if you need something differently. Given that parts of JSON.NET has code to block duplicate property names, I can't guarantee that this code will withstand updates to JSON.NET, so on the off chance that you don't already do unit tests, I suggest unit testing the code so that you know if a change to JSON.NET breaks it.